# Checking whether the email content is a plain text or HTML - PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, codeigniter

Working on Code Igniter framework, I am retrieving email using `Peeker` library.Sometimes I dont recieve the `HTML` content, just the `plain text` of the email.
For plain texts I want to replace `\r\n` with `<br>` but not for the HTML content.
I got the below `function` from `SO` to check whether the content is HTML:

```
function is_html($string)
{
  return preg_match("/<[^<]+>/",$string,$m) != 0;
}
```

Below is the few texts of plain text that I recieve:

```
On 5/15/15, Mr.X  wrote:
> Mr. Y,
>
> Congratulations! Your book has been approved by our Editorial Board for
> Publishing. Please send me all the fonts that you have used to type
> your manuscript. Please send me the font names and the font files so that
> we can proceed.......
```

But the function is returning `TRUE` for the plain text also.
How to differentiate?

Comment: Through the `$message->get_header_array();` you will get the content-type na ? I'm not used to use Peeker but found this in doc ^^

Comment: The thing is that i have not stored the content-type in the database. So somehow  from the email content only I have to differentiate

Comment: Ow mad..., did you tried out to compare `strlen($content)` and `strlen(strip_tags($content))` ?

Comment: or you can use "/<[^<>]+>/"

Comment: @Bob0t Thanx for your suggestions but i solved it by modifying the regex since i knew either a div or table would be present in almost all the html contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I know either a `<div>` or `<table>` tag will be present, I made the following changes to the regex and it worked perfectly.

```
preg_match("/<tr [\s\S]*?<\/tr>|<table [\s\S]*?<\/table>|<div [\s\S]*?<\/div>",$string) != 0;
```